# foreach variable inside asp tag doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

and in third line it's get error:
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 't' does not exist in the current context.

can somebody help me?

Comment: is that asp.net webforms or mvc?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the LinkButton inside a loop like that, nether variables like this one inside the button code. And the variable that is not found is the one inside the LinkButton.

I suggest to use repeater to make your loop, or a PlaceHolder and create the link buttons by adding controls in the same loop in the code behind.

Here is an example

```
    foreach (string s in new string[] { "ena", "dyo" })
    {
        Literal lTitle = new Literal();
        lTitle.Text = "<Br>" + s;

        LinkButton lbButton = new LinkButton();
        lbButton.Text = "<br>" + s;

        phAddOnMe.Controls.Add(lTitle);
        phAddOnMe.Controls.Add(lbButton);
    }
```

and on page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phAddOnMe"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```